# How to make Vuetify HTML table fully bordered?

Tags: html, css, vuetify.js

I have a Vue app consuming a Vuetify table that doesn't support bordered tables ( yet, see https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/16336 ). That's why I tried my own CSS to add the missing borders.

Given the following sample ( [Reproduction link](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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) )

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="(row, rowIndex) in tableMatrix" :key="rowIndex">
            <template v-for="(cell, columnIndex) in row" :key="columnIndex">
              <td v-if="cell.isCoveredByPreviousCell" class="d-none" />
              <td v-else :rowspan="cell.rowspan">
                <template v-if="cell.content">
                  {{ cell.content }}
                </template>
              </td>
            </template>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </v-table>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, Ref } from 'vue';

interface Cell { isCoveredByPreviousCell: boolean; rowspan: number; content?: string; }

type TableMatrix = Cell[][];

const childCell: Cell = { isCoveredByPreviousCell: false, rowspan: 1, content: "cell with rowspan 1" };

const tableMatrix: Ref<TableMatrix> = ref([
  [{ isCoveredByPreviousCell: false, rowspan: 2, content: "cell with rowspan 2" },{ ...childCell }],
  [{ isCoveredByPreviousCell: true, rowspan: 1, content: "covered by parent" },{ ...childCell }],
  [{ ...childCell },{ ...childCell }],
  [{ ...childCell }, { isCoveredByPreviousCell: false, rowspan: 2, content: "cell with rowspan 2" }],
  [{ ...childCell }, { isCoveredByPreviousCell: true, rowspan: 1, content: "covered by parent" }],
  [{ isCoveredByPreviousCell: false, rowspan: 2, content: "cell with rowspan 2" },{ ...childCell }],
  [{ isCoveredByPreviousCell: true, rowspan: 1, content: "covered by parent" },{ ...childCell }],
])
</script>

<style>
table { border: 1px solid #e6e6e6; }
  
table th { border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6; }

table th + th { border-left: 1px solid #e6e6e6; }

table td + td { border-left: 1px solid #e6e6e6; }
</style>
```

You can see that the last cell has a thicker border if it has a rowspan greater than 1

[image]

Does someone know which CSS "rule" is missing to fix the table border for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the `border-collapse: collapse;` property to the table.

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

> The border-collapse property sets whether table borders should
> collapse into a single border or be separated as in standard HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Uses the slot=item, then apply the styles depending on scoped-slot.

Below is one example:

Show code snippet

Uses the slot=item.name.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'start',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name',
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          iron: '7%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '8%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          iron: '16%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          iron: '0%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Lollipop',
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0,
          iron: '2%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          carbs: 87,
          protein: 6.5,
          iron: '45%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Donut',
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51,
          protein: 4.9,
          iron: '22%',
        },
        {
          name: 'KitKat',
          calories: 518,
          fat: 26.0,
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7,
          iron: '6%',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
})



.my-border {
  border-left: 5px solid red;
}



<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.3.2/dist/vuetify.min.css">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.3.2/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      :items-per-page="5"
      class="elevation-1"
    >
      <template slot="item.name" slot-scope="data">
        <div :class="data.item.calories % 2 === 0 ? 'my-border': ''">{{data.item.name}}</div>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```